# Can you complete the Stunt Jumps with the Oppressor MK1?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I was wondering if is possible to complete all 50 Stunt Jumps with the Oppressor MK1 (aka the Oppressor with real tires).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only limitation with stunt jumps is that it has to be done with a land vehicle. Thus, as the MK 1. IS in fact a land vehicle, it can perform the jumps using boost.

**HOWEVER**

Having the wings deploy during or before the jump will nullify the jump, you'll know this happened if the Cinematic Camera doesn't appear, and when you land, no text appears to say you succeeded or failed.